# How can I use Optional orElseThrow

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, option-type

spec
java 11 (openjdk11)
spring boot 2.3.6
intellij

Here is ..
[Show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1EkA.png)

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;
    public PostDto.Response getPostById(long postId) {
        Post post = postRepository.findById(postId)
                .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);    // <-- this line
        return new PostDto.Response(post);
    }
}
```

and alse
[Show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1I0u.png)

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;
    public PostDto.Response getPostById(long postId) {
        Post post = postRepository.findById(postId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());  // <-- this line
        return new PostDto.Response(post);
    }
}
```

But It works..
Why is that red underline displayed?
[Show Message1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FOV9.png)
[Show Message2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huLd9.png)

Comment: Tried to reproduce both your cases, but no luck. What does IntelliJ say when hovering mouse over the code? BR

Comment: `orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)` has been around since `Optional` was introduced in Java 8, so it cannot be a Java version problem.

Comment: Hi, please file an issue at the YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/) providing a code sample to reproduce. Thank you